# How can I allow duplicate entries in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm using phpmyadmin and want to be able to import an .sql file that contains duplicate entries in the 'code' field. I haven't been able to figure out how to get MySQL to allow it. Attached are an images that show the error when I try to import and another image showing the structure of the table in the database involved.

Any help is appreciated!

[Displayed error](http://www.ah6le.net/capture2.jpg)
[table structure as shown in phpmyadmin](http://www.ah6le.net/capture.jpg)

Here's the error

> MySQL said: Documentation #1062 - Duplicate entry '280' for key 'code'

SQL query:

```
  ALTER TABLE `commands`    
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)    
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)    
  ADD KEY `code_2` (`code`)    
  ADD KEY `code_3` (`code`,`description`,`port`,`sub`,`inputspec`,`specalt`,`comment`,`changed`)
```

Comment: No errors viewable in what you attached. Try just pasting in the text of the error.

Comment: You have defined the column `code` as UNIQUE. Why do you want duplicate values for a column which you defined as being unique? Should the `code` column have only unique values or not?

Answer (score 0):

No error in the screenshot you pasted.As per the screenshot id is your primary key not code. So, it must allow duplicate values. could you please recheck or elaborate a bit. Instead of duplicate,code column will not allow null values as you have chosen.

-Thanks,

Comment: I edited my original post to list the errors. But here's a link to exactly what I am shown http://www.ah6le.net/capture2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to allow duplicate values, then don't add a UNIQUE KEY...

```
ALTER TABLE `commands`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
  ADD KEY `code_2` (`code`)
  ADD KEY `code_3` (`code`,`description`,`port`,`sub`,`inputspec`,`specalt`,`comment`,`changed`)
```

The primary key and the multiple column key "code_3" are ok. The two lines in the middle are probably wrong and definitely superfluous.